# What is the relation of Vasant Panchami with Goddess Saraswati?

Tags: festivals, puja, saraswati

Tomorrow is Vasant Panchami and my Bengali friends shall be celebrating Saraswati Puja. I wanted to know if the worship of Saraswati is mentioned in any scripture on this particular day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vasant Panchami is the day Magha Shukla Panchami.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasant_Panchami):

> Vasant Panchami has a specific meaning: Vasant means "spring" and
>   Panchami means "the fifth day." Vasant Panchami falls on the fifth day
>   of spring.
>
> **Vasant Panchami is celebrated every year on the fifth day of the bright half of the Hindu luni-solar calendar month of Magha**, which
>   typically falls in late January or February.

You can get a scriptural reference in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.

Quoting from the [Essence of Brahma Vaivarta Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=9):

> Having described that Durga, Radha, Lakshmi, Saraswati and Savitri
>   were the Pancha Prakritis, Narayana Maharshi told Narada Muni that
>   Shri Krishna performed worship to Prakritis Amshabhuta Kala Swarupa
>   Devis viz. Vaani, Vasundhara, Ganga, Shashthi, Mangala Chandika,
>   Tulasi, Manasa, Nidra, Swadha, Swaahaa and Dakshina. Shri Krishna said
>   that in terms of Teja (Radiance), Rupa (Form) and Gunas (Features),
>   these Eleven Devis were as significant as his own. As the details of
>   worship of Durga, Radha and Lakshmi would be taken up later, Narayana
>   Rishi desired to describe the Puja Vidhana of Devi Saraswati first.
>   **Devi Saraswatis worship is the most auspicious on Megha Shukla Panchami** as ordained by Shri Krishna when all over the Universe the
>   Puja as also Vidyaarambha ( initiation of Studies) is performed by
>   human beings, Manuganas, Devatas, Muniganas, Vasus, Yogis, Siddhas,
>   Nagas, Gandharvas and Rakshasas with the traditional Shodashopacharas
>   by invoking Saraswati into a Kalasha or a Book. Then puja should be
>   done to six Devatas viz. Ganesha, Surya, Agni, Vishnu, Shiva, and Devi
>   Parvati before performing Puja to Devi Saraswati.

Comment: Actually its Sri Panchami. And Sri is Kukakundalini who expresses Herself as Vaikahari or Vaak. May be there is some link of this with Saraswati Puja prescribed on this day?

Comment: Aim is used as beeja in both Sri(Tripurasundari) and Saraswati -so there shouod be some tantrik connection also?

Comment: You mean between the fifth tithi and Saraswati? @Partha

Comment: between sri and saraswati as the tithi is called Sri Panchami even at the time of Sankalpa

Comment: Ok Sri Vidya has 3 kootas with one being the Vag bhava so there is a connection .. Saraswati is also Lalita's one eye and she is also showing as serving her with a fan @Partha

Comment: Omkarnathji pointed out one interesting thing: Aim is the beeja for Kunfdalini, Saraswati and Guru.mHe says the One who is Kundalini at Mulaadhar (Paraa),becomes Vakdevi at Vaikhari and becomes Guru at Sahasrara. Tripura means brahmagranthi, Vishnugranthi and Rudragranthi I think and so Tripuradevi is basically Kundalinimand Saraswati both